# How many sequences of five bases are there?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A and G are purines and C and T are pyrimidines. How many sequences of five bases are there that consist of three purines and two pyrimidines?

I thought that I could do : 2^3 x 2^2 = 32

my teacher uploaded a solution sheet where it says 320 ? Actually it says "320," (the comma is on purpose. I thought it could be a typo of my teacher,

so my question at you folks is can you double check my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You are computing the possible combinations for only one order, $AAABB$. Order is a key feature of sequences. There are many more orders to pick, like $AABBA, ABBAA,\dots$ Precisely $5\choose2$ or $5\choose3$ in total (they both equal $10$). Of the spots you could place a $B$ in (there are $5$), you choose $2$. Or, of the spots you could place an $A$ in ($5$, again), you choose $3$. For every order, the number of combinations is always $2^5$, as you showed. So the total number of sequences is ${5\choose2}2^5=10\cdot32=320$.